# I am getting error i.e Required field: Channel is missing

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium

I am trying to develop app with pushnotification, I am getting device token but unable to subscribe.

I am getting error i.e Required field: Channel is missing.

I did this to subscribe

```
var deviceToken;
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');
Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
        channel: 'friend_request',
        type: Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? 'gcm' : 'ios',
        device_token: deviceToken
        }, function (e) {
            if (e.success) {
                alert('Success :'+((e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
                pushNotify();
            } else {
                alert('Error:' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It appears that you can't really subscribe without having a user account logged into the ACS cloud services platform.

So either create an account or use the default one. Here's a thread on Appcelerator.com solving the same problem, and with a code sample that works.

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135641/push-notifications-with-ticloud

Answer (score 0):

Either what @Phil McCarty mentioned and make sure you are [using GCM](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Configuring_push_services-section-37551713_Configuringpushservices-ConfiguringpushservicesforAndroiddevices) and not MQTT which has been deprecated last month. Once those settings have been done, make sure the device is sending the token of the device, as you will get this same ACS message: Channel is missing if the token is wrong.